# The argument type 'CurrentUser? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CurrentUser Function(User?)'

Tags: flutter, dart

The argument type 'CurrentUser? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CurrentUser Function(User?)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
CurrentUser? _userFromFirebase(User user)
package:brew_crew/services/auth.dart

im getting this error i was creating anonimouse user login on flutter firebase
can any help me out..
code is below

```
 // Create user object based on FirebaseUser
  CurrentUser? _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    return user != null ? CurrentUser (uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change obj stream

  Stream<CurrentUser> get users{
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }
```

full code is here

```
import 'package:brew_crew/model/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService{

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // Create user object based on FirebaseUser
  CurrentUser? _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    return user != null ? CurrentUser (uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change obj stream

  Stream<CurrentUser> get users{
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  //sin in anon
  Future signInAnon() async{
   try {
  UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
  User? user = result.user;
  return _userFromFirebase(user!);
}catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}

  }

  //sign in with E-mail and password

  //Register with E-mail and passqord

  //Sign out
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your `Stream` type to `CurrentUser?`:

```dart
CurrentUser? _userFromFirebase(User user) {
  return user != null ? CurrentUser (uid: user.uid) : null;
}

//                v
Stream<CurrentUser?> get users{
  return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
}
```

Comment: Does the error still persist or is it another one?